# Writing Escape Characters to a Csv File in Python

Tags: python, file, csv, escaping

I'm using the csv module in python and escape characters keep messing up my csv's. For example, if I had the following:

```
import csv

rowWriter = csv.writer(open('bike.csv', 'w'), delimiter = ",")

text1 = "I like to \n ride my bike"
text2 = "pumpkin sauce"

rowWriter.writerow([text1, text2])
rowWriter.writerow(['chicken','wings'])
```

I would like my csv to look like:

```
I like to \n ride my bike,pumpkin sauce
chicken,wings
```

But instead it turns out as

```
I like to
ride my bike,pumpkin sauce
chicken,wings
```

I've tried combinations of quoting, doublequote, escapechar and other parameters of the csv module, but I can't seem to make it work. Does anyone know whats up with this?

*Note - I'm also using codecs encode("utf-8"), so text1 really looks like `"I like to \n ride my bike".encode("utf-8")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with writing them to the file. The problem is that `\n` is a line break when inside `''` or `""`. What you really want is either `'I like to \\n ride my bike'` or `r'I like to \n ride my bike'` (notice the `r` prefix).

Comment: That's whats up. Thanks for that. I'm still trying to figure out the best way to go about converting to the string literal. What I've found that works best is `text = "%r" % "I like to \n ride my bike".encode("utf-8")` and then using `text[1:-1]`.

Comment: @crunkchitis Why do you need to call `.encode()`? It seems like the strings you use come from your source code.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. I don't need to call encode anymore, now that I'm using the raw string. There are a lot of unicode characters in the text that I am using, so before I started using the raw string I was using encode so that csv could read the unicode text.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is not obvious why you want `r"\n"` (two bytes) to appear in your file instead of `"\n"` (one byte). What is the consumer of the output file meant to do? Use `ast.evaluate_literal()` on each input field? If your actual data contains any of (non-ASCII characters, apostrophes, quotes), then I'd be very wary of serialising it using `repr()`.

Secondly, you have misreported either your code or your output (or both). The code that you show actually produces:

```
"I like to
 ride my bike",pumpkin sauce
chicken,wings
```

Thirdly, about your `"I like to \n ride my bike".encode("utf-8")`: `str_object.encode("utf-8")` is absolutely pointless if `str_object` contains only ASCII bytes -- it does nothing. Otherwise it raises an exception.

Fourthly, this comment:

> I don't need to call encode anymore, now that I'm using the raw
>   string. There are a lot of unicode characters in the text that I am
>   using, so before I started using the raw string I was using encode so
>   that csv could read the unicode text

doesn't make any sense -- as I've said, `"ascii string".encode('utf8')` is pointless.

Consider taking a step ot two backwards, and explain what you are really trying to do: where does your data come from, what's in it, and most importantly, what does the process that is going to read the file going to do?